# Highlighted menu links

Tags: html, css, menu

I have multiple sections on my home page. When I'm in a specific section, I want that section to be highlighted in the menu.

The theme I use does this with li:current but this code doesn't always do the same thing.

It works on 2 of the 5 menu links, after I clicked them or scrolled to the section they become orange and stay orange.

The other 3 menu links become orange when clicked and when the page has scrolled to the section, the menu link loses his orange color.

When scrolled to one of these 3 sections, the menu links don't change color at all.

The sections are made with a section tag and the menu links are setup to go to the section id's.

How can I fix this?

```
<section id="portfoliosection">
    <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio" role="region" aria-label="Portfolio">
    </div>
    <div id="portfolioh2">
        <h2 class="h2portfolio">Portfolio</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio1">

        <?php wd_slider(2); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="portfoliotekst">
        <p class="portfoliotekst">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget ex finibus, pellentesque urna eu, mattis ipsum. Aenean metus elit, cursus at pharetra vehicula, maximus ut ligula. Fusce lobortis lorem in dolor dapibus elementum. Suspendisse
            ultrices ipsum lectus. Nullam lorem sapien, molestie sit amet elit ultricies, varius gravida erat. Cras ullamcorper, augue suscipit faucibus accumsan, ante nibh viverra dui, ac molestie velit arcu at metus. Duis finibus molestie velit, a efficitur
            ex finibus luctus. In justo dui, hendrerit sed quam ac, iaculis rhoncus orci. Sed cursus, mauris vel laoreet consectetur, massa tortor iaculis nisl, eget mollis nisl nunc nec metus. Phasellus eleifend elit et metus laoreet, vel bibendum arcu
            ultrices. Vivamus id augue sit amet dui lobortis posuere. Nunc accumsan ante nec mauris tincidunt, in porta tortor aliquet. Etiam posuere eget lorem ut commodo.</p>
    </div>
</section>

#portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
}

.h2portfolio {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F16C20;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#portfolio1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#portfoliotekst {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfoliotekst {
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: do mark the answer correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS3 psuedo-selectors** for this.

```
a:hover
a:visited
a:active
```

-- OR --

You can give them a new-class *"selected"* when it is clicked and define ".selected" in your CSS file.

```
.selected{
    color : red;
}
```